# how the size of jpanel components in a specific layout can be set?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, layout-manager, preferredsize

I'm a beginner and I want to design the gui of the windows calculator in java. I have set some  jpanels(Gridlayout) with some jbuttons in each. I set the size of the buttons this way:

```
jButton[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(42, 42));
```

but buttons in differen jpanels don't have the same size.
what should I do?

Comment: can you post all the code you have right now?

Comment: unfortunately, this is not allowed here!

Comment: [Don't use `setPreferredSize()` when you really mean to override `getPreferredSize()`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513).

Comment: `unfortunately, this is not allowed here!` - Correct, we don't want your application. We do want a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) which demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jButton[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(42, 42));
```

There are 3 easy ways to make buttons larger.

- Use a big `Icon` for the button
- Use a big `Font` for the button (preferably via a PLAF).
- Set a large margin around the text and icon.

As to setting the preferred size.  See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.)

If you are still intent on going that route, take the advice of @trashgod and *override* the preferred size instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should also set the same size for your jpanels

ie. `jpanel.setBounds(startingWidth, startingHeight, actualWidth, actualHeight);`

and then add these to your container panel.

Comment: Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556), along with layout padding & borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17874717/418556).